# Convert Python's internal str to print equivalent

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, utf8-decode

Currently I have:

```
 >> class_name = 'AEROSPC\xc2\xa01A'
 >> print(class)
 >> AEROSPC 1A
 >> 'AEROSPC 1A' == class_name
 >> False
```

How can I convert `class_name` into 'AEROSPC 1A'? Thanks!

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convert to Unicode

You get interesting errors when converting that, I first converted to utf8:

```
my_utf8 = 'AEROSPC\xc2\xa01A'.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
my_utf8
```

returns:

```
u'AEROSPC\xa01A'
```

and then I normalize the string, the \xa0 is a non-breaking space.

```
import unicodedata

my_normed_utf8 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', my_utf8)
print my_normed_utf8
```

prints:

```
AEROSPC 1A
```

### Convert back to String

which I can then convert back to an ASCII string:

```
my_str = str(my_normed_utf8)
print my_str
```

prints:

```
AEROSPC 1A
```